# Randomly select class attribute in Python

Tags: python, class, attributes, instance

```
class person():
    def __init__(self):
        self.height = 3.0
        self.weight = 240.0
        self.temp = 99.23

        self.statlist = [self.height, self.weight, self.temp]

    def grow(self):
        self.statlist[1] = self.statlist[1] + 26.0
```

What is the best way to approach this?

The problem is that I'm trying to access these 'stat' attributes from a list and alter them, but I really don't know how to call them. I need to do this so I can randomly choose a stat to modify.  Should I make a stat class, so that each stat is an instance of that class?

Any help would be magnificent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random

class person():
    def __init__(self):
        self.height = 3.0
        self.weight = 240.0
        self.temp = 99.23

        self.attrlist = ['height', 'weight', 'temp']

    def grow(self):
        rand_attr = random.choice(self.attrlist)
        attr_value = getattr(self, rand_attr)
        setattr(self, rand_attr, attr_value + 26.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

use getattr() and setattr():

```
import random
class person():
    def __init__(self):
        self.height = 3.0
        self.weight = 240.0
        self.temp = 99.23

        self.statlist = ["height", "weight", "temp"]

    def grow(self):
        name = random.choice(self.statlist)
        setattr(self, name, getattr(self, name) + 26.0)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%f, %f, %f" % (self.height, self.weight, self.temp)

p = person()
print p
p.grow()
print p
p.grow()
print p
```

output is:

```
3.000000, 240.000000, 99.230000
3.000000, 266.000000, 99.230000
3.000000, 266.000000, 125.230000
```